# Seach Page Split into Form Block & Results Block

Tags: views, 8, theming, blocks, search

I already created a search view like /search it is giving form and results finely but Views UI is disabled in my server . 
So i want to split this search page into

1) A block which contains a search form

2) A block which will show appropriate results with form field data.

I created a TWIG file to display form and results on same page as search.html.twig

It is displaying form finely but not displaying any results. Can anybody suggest what i am wrong here?

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'view',
    css_name|clean_class,
    view.current_display|clean_class
  ]
%}

<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
<h1>Sitewide Search</h1>
{{ title_prefix }}
{{ title }}
{{ title_suffix }}

 <div class="search-page-options">
  {{ drupal_entity('block', 'exposedformacquia_searchpage_2', check_access=false) }}
 </div>

 {% if pager %}
   <div class="view-header">
     {{ header }}
   </div>
   <div class="top-pager">{{ pager }}</div>
 {% endif %}

 {% if rows %}
   <h2 class="result-header">Search Results</h2>
   <div class="view-content">
     {{ rows }}
   </div>
 {% endif %}

 {% if empty %}
   <div class="view-empty">
     {{ empty }}
   </div>
 {% endif %}

 {% if pager %}
    {% if footer %}
   <div class="view-footer">
     {{ footer }}
   </div>
 {% endif %}

 <div class="bottom-pager">{{ pager }}</div>
  {% endif %}

</div>
```

Comment: Can i create a page or page template for this?

Comment: yea, just use `page--search.html.twig`

Comment: But problem is view already displaying search form again. How can i disable it from view search?